# Using Google Breakpad for MinGW-w64 applicaition

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, mingw-w64, google-breakpad

I'm trying to integrate Google Breakpad into a Windows Qt project.

When I compile it with MinGW（not w64), the Breakpad worked as expected and generated a Minidump file when the app crashes.

However, when I compile the same code with MinGW-w64, the app just crashes scielently without the Minidump file.

This issue can be reproduced by a simple test program:

```
#include "breakpad/client/windows/handler/exception_handler.h"
#include "breakpad/client/windows/sender/crash_report_sender.h"

void test()
{
    // install the exception handler
    std::wstring prod(L"some prod");
    std::wstring ver(L"some ver");
    std::wstring subver(L"some subver");
    static google_breakpad::CustomInfoEntry custom_entries[] = {
        google_breakpad::CustomInfoEntry(L"prod", prod.c_str()),
        google_breakpad::CustomInfoEntry(L"ver", ver.c_str()),
        google_breakpad::CustomInfoEntry(L"subver", subver.c_str()),
    };
    static google_breakpad::CustomClientInfo custom_info = {custom_entries, 3};

    std::wstring path(L"some/path/to/dump/file");
    auto handler = new google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler(path, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler::HANDLER_ALL, MiniDumpNormal, (const wchar_t *)nullptr, &custom_info);

    // feed crash
    *(int*)0x1 = 1; 
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is compiled together with the Breakpad source tree (not as a binary library)

It seems like that the exception handler is not called. A callback function will not be called if I register it to the ctor of `google_breakpad::ExceptionHandler`.

So why does it happen? Is it possible to integrate Breakpad into a MinGW-w64-compiled project?

Comment: I can compile with mingw w64 and dump file is created. But how to open in analyze it?